# Lists or vectors within a column of a data frame, to be able to compare each value and count the matches with R project

Tags: r, vector

'Lists or vectors within a column of a data frame, to be able to compare each value and count the matches with R project'

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3,2,20,6 |
| b | 3,0,20,15 |
| a | 3,2,20,50 |
| b | 3,6,59,0 |
| a | 3,4,20,6 |

'I have two columns, Col2 is a character, but I need to transform it to a vector, example:
c(“3”, ”2”, ”20”, ”6”, ”4”, ”64”, ”7”, ”65”, ”76”, ”26”, ”52”, ”67”, ”66”, ”76”, ”22”), to be able to apply %in% and obtain the number of True, example:'

'Table$Col3 <- Table$Col2[1] %in% Table$Col2 and get'

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3,2,20,6 |  |
| b | 3,0,20,15 | true, false, true, false |
| a | 3,2,20,50 |  |
| b | 3,6,59,0 | true, false, false, false |
| a | 3,4,20,6 | true, false, true, false |

'And finally count the number of True'

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3,2,20,6 |  |  |
| b | 3,0,20,15 | true, false, true, false | 2 |
| a | 3,2,20,50 | true, true, true, false | 3 |
| b | 3,6,59,0 | true, false, false, false | 1 |
| a | 3,4,20,6 | true, false, true, false | 2 |

'But I cannot transform Table$Col2[1] into a vector or list, I always get all the content between quotes “c(“3”, ”2”, ”20”, ”6”, ”4”, ”64” , ”7”, ”65”, ”76”, ”26”, ”52”, ”67”, ”66”, ”76”, ”22”)”, as a single value, in this way it compares the entire lists, not the values inside, not each value.'

'How can I solve that? It occurs to me that I could separate the values, creating more columns formatted as integers, and then join the values to create the vector or list, but I think that would be very inefficient.'

Comment: Are you comparing with the first `list` element in 'Col2'.  You need `Table$Col2[[1]]` to extract as `vector`.  The logic is not clear

Comment: Would you `dput` your data ?

Comment: @akrun: 'yes i want to compare the values of the first row with the rest fr rows'

Comment: @LauraMorcilloSánchez why is the third row for Col3 empty.  There is value 64 that is common in both 3rd and 1st row?

Comment: @MohamedDesouky Desouky: 'my real data is very similar I have simplified it to be able to put it here'

Comment: @akrun: 'ok, I understand you, I'm sorry I've set it to random for not taking so long, it doesn't correspond to reality, if it's confusing, I'll change it'

Comment: Not sure whether the expected output matches with the input based on your logic i.e. try `library(dplyr);library(purrr); df1 %>% mutate(Col3 = imap(Col2, ~ if(.y == 1) NA else .x %in% Col2[[1]]), Col4 = map_dbl(Col3, ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: with your new data, the count values are not corresponding to the values i.e. 5th have 3 matches and 4th 2 matches

Comment: i.e. `3 4 20 6` and `3 2 20 6` have 3 values common

Answer (score 2):

We may extract the first `list` element with `[[`, loop over the `list` column with `map/imap` (from `purrr`), create a logical vector with `%in%` and get the count of TRUE values in `Col4` by taking the sum of TRUE (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Col3 = imap(Col2, ~ if(.y == 1) NA else .x %in% Col2[[1]]), 
     Col4 = map_dbl(Col3, ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Col1  Col2      Col3       Col4
  <chr> <list>    <list>    <dbl>
1 a     <dbl [4]> <lgl [1]>     0
2 b     <dbl [4]> <lgl [4]>     2
3 a     <dbl [4]> <lgl [4]>     3
4 b     <dbl [4]> <lgl [4]>     2
5 a     <dbl [4]> <lgl [4]>     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a"), Col2 = list(
    c(3, 2, 20, 6), c(3, 0, 20, 15), c(3, 2, 20, 50), c(3, 6, 
    59, 0), c(3, 4, 20, 6))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: just to point out OP stated that `Col2` is character and not list

Comment: @akrun: 'Thank you very much for helping me, sorry for the delay in answering, but I didn't know the purrr package and I've been looking at it, I'm having a hard time understanding this part: ~ if(.y == 1) NA else .x %in% Col2[[1 ]],'

'Can you explain it to me in more detail?'
'is Col2[[1]] Table$Col2[1]?'
'.y is the row?'
'.x are the values inside each row?'

'The function does what I am looking for, the problem is the way the results are output, I need to add the Col4 column to the original data frame, what I get here is a new data frame with another format'

Comment: @LauraMS `imap` returns the value and key or  name.  If the vector or column (here it is `Col2` is unnamed, the `.x` returns the value i.e .each of the list elements, whereas `.y` returns the sequence of the list 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.   Since we are comparing the first element with the rest, i thought to keep the comparision to the rest of the elements, instead of the first with first, thus used `.y == 1` i.e. for the first element in list, return NA or else do the comparison

Comment: @LauraMS regarding adding the new column to original, use `<-` i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>%...` as `%>%` wouldn't update the original dataset